# Linq syntax method group by and subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by, subquery

Is this query possible with linq?

```
    SELECT 
    SUM([Weight]) * (SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM dbo.Prices WHERE '2020-04-02' BETWEEN [From] AND [To] AND ScrapId = CS.ScrapId), [FromCompany] ,CS.[ScrapId]
    FROM [dbo].[CollectedScrap] AS CS
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-29' GROUP BY[ScrapId], [FromCompany]
```

Latest test:

```
content.table.Where(cs => cs.Date > from)
                .Where(cs => cs.Date < to)
                .GroupBy(collectedGroup => new { collectedGroup.ScrapId, collectedGroup.FromCompany})
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    total = group.Sum(c => c.Weight) * _context.Prices.Select(p => new { p.ScrapId, p.Value, p.From, p.To })
                                                                .Where(a => a.From > from)
                                                                .Where(a => a.To < to)
                                                                .Where(a => a.ScrapId == group.Select(gr => new { gr.ScrapId }).First().ScrapId)
                                                                .FirstOrDefault()

                }).ToList();
```

There is not a direct relation between the tables. I use a subquery to get the correct price by date and multiply it with sum result of a group by query.

Comment: Despite not existing a relation, you could do manually a join `from reg in table join price in prices...`. Check the [join clause documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) and its examples

Comment: Thanks for the respone. I already tried the join method:). I don`t know how to use a where inside a join with a syntact method.

Comment: you could make a the following statement: (from reg in table join price in prices select ....).where(....)

Comment: something similar to `from reg in context.table join price in (from p in context.prices where [subquery_conditions]...) prices on ... where [main_query_conditions]`

Answer (score 0):

```
content.table.Join(
                        _context.Prices,
                        collectedScrap => collectedScrap.ScrapId,
                        price => price.ScrapId,
                        (collectedScrap, price) => new
                        {
                            label = collectedScrap.Scrap.Label,
                            date = collectedScrap.Date,
                            price = price.Value,
                            scrap = collectedScrap.Scrap.Label,
                            weight = collectedScrap.Weight
                        }
                    )
                    .Where(d => d.date > from)
                    .Where(d => d.date < to)                    
                    .Select(result => new
                    {
                        scrap = result.label,
                        weight = result.weight,
                        price = result.price,
                        total = result.price * result.weight
                    }).ToList();
```

*With normal SQL I can use a condition for the join. How can I use a WHERE inside the join. Now it`s almost behaving as a Right join.(I need to limit the join to one result).*       ----- testing with groupjoin now

generated sql:

```
SELECT [collectedScrap.Scrap].[Label] AS [scrap], [collectedScrap].[Weight], [price].[Value] AS [price], [price].[Value] * [collectedScrap].[Weight] AS [total]
FROM [CollectedScrap] AS [collectedScrap]
LEFT JOIN [Scrap] AS [collectedScrap.Scrap] ON [collectedScrap].[ScrapId] = [collectedScrap.Scrap].[ID]
INNER JOIN [Prices] AS [price] ON [collectedScrap].[ScrapId] = [price].[ScrapId]
WHERE ([collectedScrap].[Date] > @__from_0) AND ([collectedScrap].[Date] < @__to_1)
```